# Python3: How to use set_description with tqdm.contrib.concurrent process_map

Tags: python, parallel-processing, tqdm

I have been using process_map from tqdm.contrib.concurrent : https://tqdm.github.io/docs/contrib.concurrent/

How can I set a description with the progress bar which changes in every iteration?

I have tried with: (stripped out a lot of code to simplify it here...)

```
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map 
import tqdm

def myfunc(htmlfile):

    tqdm.tqdm.set_description(htmlfile)

    ### function contents go here

r = process_map(myfunc, mylist, max_workers=16)
```

But I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'desc'`

Is it because process_map from `tqdm.contrib.concurrent` cannot be mixed with set_description from `tqdm.tqdm` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: `process_map` accepts an additional list of keyword arguments which are directly passed on to tqdm. This means you can simply use an additional keyword argument `desc` as follows.

```py
r = process_map(myfunc, mylist, max_workers=16, desc="My Description")
```

---

AFAIK, there's no easy way to do this (as of yet). However, `process_map` takes an optional parameter called `tqdm_class` which you can use to your advantage ([docs](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/contrib.concurrent/#process_map)).

You can create a custom class which inherits the default class `tqdm.tqdm` and set attributes accordingly.

```py
import tqdm

class my_tqdm(tqdm.tqdm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.desc = "My Description"
```

You can then pass on this custom class to `process_map`

```py
r = process_map(myfunc, mylist, max_workers=16, tqdm_class=my_tqdm)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of `tqdm` (4.66.1), you just need to pass `desc` to `process_map`.

Example:

```
process_map(myfunc, mylist, max_workers=16, desc="your_description_here")
```